# How to submit the form on checking the checkbox with its value in rails 4?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using rails4. I want to submit the form on checking and unchecking it, with its value true and false respectively. I have done this but its not working properly, Please help me to do it in a correct way.

```
<% @metals.each do |metal| %>
<%= form_for([@product,metal]) do |f|%>
  <%=f.check_box :selected , {}, "true", "false" %>
<%end%>
<%end%>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {

       $(".edit_metal").submit();

     });
  });
 </script>
```

The form is in the loop and first entry in the loop is not working, rest all are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the metal.id to the form in the html tag and did it by this-

```
var metal_id = document.getElementById(this.id);
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    var metal_id = document.getElementById($(this).parent().attr("id"));
    $(metal_id).submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't handle the click() event, use the change() event, as:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {    
  $(".edit_metal").submit();
});
```

Comment: `change` and `click` events on the check boxes returns the same values for "checked" : https://jsfiddle.net/j1pe4cmc/